# Cookies not set on deployed React app on AWS S3

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, nestjs

In NestJS i created backend for my app and i used ReactJS for frontend. When i was testing on localhost everything was working fine.
Then i wanted to try and learn some AWS and i made docker image of my backend and deployed it to EC2.  After that i got this url:
`http://ec2-<SomeNumbers>.<SomeRegion>.compute.amazonaws.com:8080`. If i use this url in Postman and do a POST to my login it works fine. I get back JWT as HttpOnly cookie. In my ReactJS app i replaced localhost links with this new link.

I uploaded my ReactJS app to AWS S3 and got this url `http://<bucketName>.s3-website.<Region>.amazonaws.com`. If i open this it shows correct first page. The problem comes when i fill login form and click login button the JWT cookie is not set so i get Unauthorized.

I really do not know is the problem in my backend, frontend or in AWS settings.

NestJS controller login function:

```
async login(
    @Body() body: LoginUserDto,
    @Res({ passthrough: true }) response: Response,
  ) {
    const data = await this.authService.login(body);
    response.cookie('jwt', data, { httpOnly: true });
    return 'success';
  }
```

ReactJS code:

```
const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://ec2-<SomeNumbers>.<SomeRegion>.compute.amazonaws.com:8080",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
  withCredentials: true,
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: when you are setting cookies, you set ```httpOnly``` flag, if the request and response is over https in aws, you will have trouble setting the cookies, that is why it is running fine in localhost and not through frontend. Do check it.

Comment: I am new to this so sorry if i didn't understand what you meant, but my URLs are http not https. But after some research i found that you can't set `httpOnly` cookies if you have different domains. So i think that is my issue?